# Query to flatten a few query records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query in SSMS 2019 to change this data:

```
Key  Value  Count
-----------------
  1    2      2
  1    4      1
```

BUT I don't know which SQL query commands to get me the needed result as a single row as shown here:

```
Key   NormalValue   SpecialValue
--------------------------------
 1        2              1
```

- The `NormalValue` is the `COUNT()` for the value of 2 (=2).
- The `SpecialValue` is the COUNT() for the value of 4 (=1).

To clarify the query DATA is Key (standard), value is the
importance-value for the Key-record and the Count is the number of
related records that have the importance of either 2 or 4 or 8 or
other combinations (1,2,4,8).  The wanted result is to show the
Count()'s for importance-value of 2 and 4 in a single records for the
KEY.

Comment: Why isn't Special Value 1? You have 4 listed in your desired results. Regardless, look into using two `case expressions`.

Comment: To clarify the query DATA is Key (standard), value is the importance-value for the Key-record and the Count is the number of related records that have the importance of either 2 or 4 or 8 or other combinations (1,2,4,8).  The wanted result is to show the Count()'s for importance-value of 2 and 4 in a single records for the KEY.

Comment: You are correct... the SpecialValue should be 1 not 4.  Thank you for pointing this out for my clarifiaction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` to achieve your results. But it's still unclear why you have a desired output of 4 rather than 1 for your special value. I presume that's a typo because it contradicts your explanation.

```
create table my_table (
  ikey integer, 
  ivalue integer, 
  icount integer
  );
```

```
insert into my_table values 
(1, 2, 2), 
(1, 4, 1), 
(2, 2, 10);
```

```
select 
  ikey, 
  max(case when ivalue = 2 then icount end) as normal_value, 
  max(case when ivalue = 4 then icount end) as special_value
from my_table
group by ikey
```

| ikey | normal_value | special_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vR1s1x9k)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I set this as the ANSWER.  I also added some clarifying text-comments that you pointed out my typo of 1 2 4 changing it to 1 2 1 as your solution is correct.  Thank you for being so smart!!!  thx.  BTW -- I am not sure why to placed MAX(...) in your solution.  Can you please explain? thx

Comment: @JohnD Without the max() and group_by, you would have two rows for Key 1 because it matches both case expressions. It would look like 1-2-null and 1-null-1. You can play around in the fiddle and try different queries to see impacts.